# How to deregister $rootScope.$on in app.run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, rootscope

I am broadcasting an event in my app controller:

```
var locationSrt = location.toString();
if(locationSrt.indexOf("?RecoverPassword") !== -1) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('recover-password');
}
```

Then in my `app.js` in `app.run` I have `$rootScope.$on` (from what I read `app.run`  doesn't support `$scope`)

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('recover-password', function () {
        $location.path("/recover-password");
    });
});
```

The problem is `$rootScope.$on` is called every time in login controller even though condition `locationSrt.indexOf("?RecoverPassword") !== -1` is no longer true as the `location.search` is set to `$window.location.search = '';`

How can I prevent `$rootScope.$on` from being called again?

Comment: Can you show more code from your login controller?

Comment: I've only got this at the moment. It's the app controller, not login controller sorry.

Comment: Why is it broadcasting the `recover-password` event if the condition is no longer true?